# How to add a custom view helper in zend framework2?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I used the skeleton zf2 application from github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an excerpt from the [ZF2](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/index.html) reference that should get you started:

> **14.4.2. Registering Helpers** Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer composes a plugin broker for managing helpers, specifically an instance of
>   Zend\View\HelperBroker, which extends the base plugin broker in order
>   to ensure we have valid helpers available. The HelperBroker by default
>   uses Zend\View\HelperLoader as its helper locator. The HelperLoader is
>   a map-based loader, which means that you will simply map the
>   helper/plugin name by which you wish to refer to it to the actual
>   class name of the helper/plugin.
>
> Programmatically, this is done as follows:

```
// $view is an instance of PhpRenderer
$broker = $view->getBroker();
$loader = $broker->getClassLoader();

// Register singly:
$loader->registerPlugin('lowercase', 'My\Helper\LowerCase');

// Register several:
$loader->registerPlugins(array(
    'lowercase' => 'My\Helper\LowerCase',
    'uppercase' => 'My\Helper\UpperCase',
));
```

> Within an MVC application, you will typically simply pass a map of
>   plugins to the class via your configuration.

```
// From within a configuration file
return array(
    'di' => array('instance' => array(
        'Zend\View\HelperLoader' => array('parameters' => array(
            'map' => array(
                'lowercase' => 'My\Helper\LowerCase',
                'uppercase' => 'My\Helper\UpperCase',
            ),
        )),
    )),
);
```

> The above can be done in each module that needs to register helpers
>   with the PhpRenderer; however, be aware that another module can
>   register helpers with the same name, so order of modules can impact
>   which helper class will actually be registered!
>
> **14.4.3. Writing Custom Helpers** Writing custom helpers is easy. We recommend extending Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper, but at the
>   minimum, you need only implement the Zend\View\Helper interface:

```
namespace Zend\View;

interface Helper
{
    /**
     * Set the View object
     *
     * @param  Renderer $view
     * @return Helper
     */
    public function setView(Renderer $view);

    /**
     * Get the View object
     *
     * @return Renderer
     */
    public function getView();
}
```

> If you want your helper to be capable of being invoked as if it were a
>   method call of the PhpRenderer, you should also implement an
>   __invoke() method within your helper.
>
> As previously noted, we recommend extending
>   Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper, as it implements the methods defined
>   in Helper, giving you a headstart in your development.
>
> Once you have defined your helper class, make sure you can autoload
>   it, and then register it with the plugin broker.
>
> Here is an example helper, which we're titling "SpecialPurpose"

```
namespace My\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class SpecialPurpose extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $count = 0;

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $this->count++;
        $output = sprintf("I have seen 'The Jerk' %d time(s).", $this->count);
        return htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

> Then assume that when we register it with the plugin broker, we map it
>   to the string "specialpurpose".
>
> Within a view script, you can call the SpecialPurpose helper as many
>   times as you like; it will be instantiated once, and then it persists
>   for the life of that PhpRenderer instance.

```
// remember, in a view script, $this refers to the Zend_View instance.
echo $this->specialPurpose();
echo $this->specialPurpose();
echo $this->specialPurpose();
```

> The output would look something like this:
>
> I have seen 'The Jerk' 1 time(s). I have seen 'The Jerk' 2 time(s). I
>   have seen 'The Jerk' 3 time(s).